# Const references sometimes lead to confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I'm new to C++. I learned that references should be used whenever possible and that pointers should be used only when strictly necessary. I also learned that `const` references should be used in function parameters when the function does not change the referred variable.

I understand the reasons and agree with them, but there's a common case where `const` references lead to confusion which is when a mutable object "becomes immutable" as an effect (const-ness) of declaring a `const` reference to an object. For example, the `Foo` class has a method named `incrementX()` which mutate the state of `Foo` when called:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        void incrementX();
    private:
        private int x;
}
void Foo::incrementX() {
    x++;
}
class Bar {
    public:
        void doSomethingWith(const Foo &foo);
}
void Bar::doSomethingWith(const Foo &foo) {
    foo.incrementX(); // <- illegal because incrementX() is not a const method
}
int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    bar.doSomethingWith(foo);
}
```

The usual solution is to declare `incrementX()` as a `const` method, which in turn forces me to declare the variable `x` as a `mutable` variable. The problem is, by turning `incrementX()` into a `const` method I'm saying that this method is not supposed to mutate the object's state, which is not true in the above example. Not only it's not true, it's also the method's intent to mutate the object's state.

I'm curious how experienced C++ programmers deal with this situation. I'm inclined to use `const` pointers (`Foo * const foo`) in such cases, would that be recommended/discourage?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify the cause of my confusion, I often hear people saying *"use const refs when the function promises not to change the parameter"*, but what exactly *"to change the parameter"* means? Does it mean the function promises not to assign a new object to the parameter, or does it mean it will not mutate the objects's state? Of course, `const` references disallow both kind of changes, but **what's the main concern when it comes to `const` references?** Is it that it will not assign a new value to the parameter, or is it that it will not mutate the state of the object referred to by the `const` reference?

Comment: If you need the caller to have the modifications back, use a non-const reference. If not, pass by value.

Comment: If the function is supposed to modify its parameter, then the parameter shouldn't be `const`.

Comment: What does _modify its parameter_ mean? Does it mean _to replace `foo` with another instance of Foo_ or does it mean _to mutate foo's state_?

Comment: @le_ninja_sloth: It means to modify any of its non-`mutable` members, or to call any non-`const` member function. (There's no concept of "replacing an object" in C++; I assume you mean "assigning with another value", which is done by calling a non-`const` assignment operator.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour that's exactly what I meant by "replacing an object", sorry I chose the wrong words. Ok, now I get it. When I heard people saying _"use const refs when your function promises not to change the parameter"_ I thought they meant the function promises not to assign a new value to the parameter.

Comment: @MikeSeymour So the fact that the function can assign a new object to the non-`const` parameter should not be a concern?

Comment: @le_ninja_sloth: If it's not `const`, then it can modify it in any way. If it is, then it can't modify it at all. There's no (simple) way to allow some types of modifications but not others. Whether or not that's a concern depends on what you happen to be concerned about.

Comment: @chris: Poor advice. The very point of const references is to *avoid* the object copy necessary when passing by value.

Comment: @DevSolar, I didn't mean to always use those two. We've established that const reference is not an option here. For advice that includes that, keep the non-const reference the same and then if you need to make local modifications (need a copy of the argument), pass by value, else const reference. Of course that doesn't even cover rvalue references, but taking by rvalue reference isn't all that common anyway.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That's the advice I'd give as well, but chris made it sound as if references are for out-parameters only and any other case should be handled by pass-by-value, which -- I stand by that -- is poor advice. (*Both* the out-parameter *and* the pass-by-value for in-parameters that don't need to be worked on locally.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think that answers my question, thank you. I already understood the semantics of `const` references but I was confused when people suggested to use `const` references to **document** that my function will not _change the parameter_.

Answer (score 1):

By taking `const Foo &`

```
void Bar::doSomethingWith(const Foo &foo)
```

promises not to modify the `foo`. Therefore it may not call it's non-const `incrementX` method.

If you have `Bar::doSomethingWith(Foo &foo)` that needs to call `foo.incrementX` (and therefore needs to take it's argument non-const reference), than you should reconsider whether it is really appropriate to be a method of `Bar` and not `Foo` in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. When I heard people saying _use const refs when your function promises not to change the parameter in question_ I (wrongfully) thought that the main premise was that the function promised not to assign a new value to the parameter, like this: `foo = Foo()`.

Comment: @le_ninja_sloth there are numerous ways in C++ to modify a parameter. Your `incrementX` function modified the the object's `x` member variable, and so modifies the object itself.

Comment: @le_ninja_sloth: Remember, that `foo = Foo()` is a shorthand for `foo.operator=(Foo())`. Because reference is alias for the value and assignment to a value is just a call to it's special method assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass by const reference if you expect that your object will be changed, or overload the function so that you have `doSomethingWith(const Foo&)` and `doSomethingWith(Foo&)`.

The whole idea is that passing by `const` reference forces `const` behaviour, so you can only invoke member functions that are marked `const`, and this leads to less problems in the long run.

PS: I made the `doSomething` a member of `Foo`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    int m=0;
public:
    void doSomething(const Foo& foo) const
    {
        cout << "calling const reference" << endl;

    }

    void doSomething(Foo& foo)
    {
        cout << "calling reference" << endl;
        foo.m++;
    }

};


int main()
{
    const Foo f,g ;
    f.doSomething(g); // calls const reference

    Foo h,k;
    h.doSomething(k); // calls reference
}
```